# Identity Server 4 Missing custom claims in client

Tags: c#, .net, identityserver4

I'm using Identity Server 4 to secure an ASP.NET MVC application using authorization code with pkce. When I log the claims in the index page my custom claims are missing when I log the claims:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var claims = User.Claims.Select(x => x);

    foreach (var claim in claims)
    {
        _logger.LogDebug("{type}: {scope}", claim.Type, claim.Value);
    }

    return View("Index");
}
```

Result

```
s_hash: 60vq3E...
sid: 35B6E3...
http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier: 123123
auth_time: 1699123123
http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/identityprovider: local
http://schemas.microsoft.com/claims/authnmethodsreferences: pwd
uid: 123123
unm: username
```

However when I look at the identity store `PersistedGrants` table, I can see my custom claims:

```
{
    "Type": "mycustomclaim",
    "Value": "mycustomclaim",
    "ValueType": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
}
```

Additionally, the scope claims are missing as well in the log but can be found in the `PersistedGrants` table.

Is there a way to pass the missing claims to the application so I can implement a policy like this?

```
options.AddPolicy("mypolicy", policy =>
{
    policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
    policy.RequireClaim("mycustomclaim", "mycustomclaim");
});
```

Comment: Show us your `IClientStore` implementation. And where are you populating `mycustomclaim`'s value from? Are they _Client Claims_ - or _User Claims_?

Comment: Its populated in the profileservice and it should be access claims

Comment: We need to see that code...